# JAX-WS unable to create new native thread SOAPFaultException

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, axis, wildfly-8

I'm having this exception when I try to consume a WebService from my application. I've been googling this error but all I see is about OutOfMemoryErrror.

I have Wildfly 8.1.0.Final and  jaxws-api version 2.2.9 as dependency in my pom.xml. I'm using axis 1.4 for another legacy module of my application too. I've read in another stackoverflow post that I can't use both (Axis and CXF) in the same project (or .war finally) but I can't find any other reference about this fact.

I tried disabling webservices extensions in my standalone.xml with no success at all. Also adding jbossws-cxf-client 5.0.0.Final in my pom.xml with the same result.

Tomorrow I'll try to generate an Axis 1.4 client and see if this solves my problem.

Thanks in advance for any comment.

```
21:06:54,634 ERROR [....controller.BaseController] (default task-17) Manejando una excepción no tratada: javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: unable to create new native thread
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:157)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy100.evaluateTransaction(Unknown Source)
at ...services.RiskServicesImpl.consultarRiesgoTx(RiskServicesImpl.java:191) [classes:]
```

Comment: When you remove either Axis or CXF, leaving one remaining, does this exception go away?

Answer (score 0):

Finally we realized that this SOAPFaultException was not thrown from my Wildfly but from the server we wanted to connect to, wich ran out of memory. Using another tool to query de web service was enough to see this.

Tim Biegeleisen: thanks for reading this desperate post :)